# What is this white growth under my hibiscus?

Tags: identification, hibiscus

Does anyone know what this is at the bottom of the hibiscus? What needs to be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obviously fungal growth, but there's a possibility it might have been a shelf fungus or similar which has collapsed or been broken up, hard to say. It depends what it's growing on - if it's directly firmly attached to the woody stems, it might indicate a fatal problem at the roots or base of the stems in the plant, but if it's growing off something loose on the ground, like dead wood or debris, it might not be an issue. If the upper parts of the plant are completely healthy and continue to be so, it may not be something to worry about, but keep checking for signs of disease or die back in the Hibiscus,and any further formation of fungus on the stems, when it may need to be removed eventually. There is nothing you can do other than clear away any dead debris from the ground.